# What is the cause of the syntax error in greater than or equal "if statement"?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, syntax

The following code I wrote was part of an in-class exercise on making "if-statements" in python, which I saved as x.py.

```
    name = raw_input()("Please enter your name:")
print ("Hello", name)
age = int(raw-input("what is your age?"))
print "according to you, your age is", age
print "in a year you will be ", age +1
#if age is >= 21 print "In the state of Massachusetts, you can legally purchase alcoholic drinks"
if age is => 21:
    print "In the state of Massachusetts, you can legally purchase alcoholic drinks." 
else:
    print " something else…"
    print "here’s one more thing…"
```

The problem is that when I try to run the program in Terminal, I get the following error:

```
  File "x.py", line 7
    if age is => 21:
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried reentering the line, looking up examples of conditional statements, and scouring stackoverflow for similar questions, but couldn't find any that had an error that was very close to mine. I also can't reach my professor or my TA because of the snowstorm in New England. I'm using Python 2.7.9 on a mac book in v10.9.5. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: It's `>=`. You call it *greater than or equal to*, not *equal to or greater than*, hence first `>` then `=`. The syntax for operators is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators). Also the you cannot use two operators one after an other (`is` and `>=`).

Comment: Numerous things are wrong with this. When you are programming, everything has to be *exact* and spelled perfectly. It's `raw_input(prompt_str)` not `raw_input()(prompt_str)` or `raw-input`. It's `if x < y` or `if x is y` not `if x is < y`, etc.

Comment: Change the line `if age is => 21:` to `if age >= 21:`.  There is no `is` and (as Bakuriu said), the greater than sign comes before the equals.  The Internet is flooded with examples of proper `if` statements.  What you need to do, as you're learning programming, is to look carefully and see that each character is right.  Two-Bit Alchemist found a few more errors that Python would have complained about after you get past this one.

Answer (score 0):

While there are numerous syntax errors in the code you posted as addressed in my comment, the one you asked about is this:

The operator `is` means "is the exact same object as" and is normally used to compare objects with `None`.

The operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=` are mathematical comparison operators and are written as is normal in mathematics or symbolic logic, e.g. `x < y`.

These operators cannot be combined and it makes no sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there exists a syntax error.

```
if age >= 21:
    print "In the..."
```

or:

```
if age is 21:
    print "In the..."
```

Comment: Don't use `is` to test for numeric equality. Use `==`; CPython happens to reuse small integer objects and thus `is` identity tests *may* work, but this is not guaranteed in the language.